# SQL Server - Replace datatime field with another date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to replace a particular datetime value with another one. I tried it with:

```
SELECT REPLACE(t.date,'1999-01-01 00:00:00.000','1900-01-01 00:00:00.000')
FROM table t
```

But that results into

```
Jan  1 1999 12:00AM
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is this specific to one date, as shown, or is the logic more complicated? Do you just want 1999 to be 1900, or do you want every date to be rolled back by 99 years?

Comment: @3BK It's just specific to that date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `replace()` on a `datetime` datatype, but you can use a combination of `isnull()` and `nullif()`, or a `case` expression.

using `isnull(nullif())`:

```
select isnull(nullif(t.date,'1999-01-01 00:00:00.000'),'1900-01-01 00:00:00.000')
from table t
```

using a `case` expression:

```
select case when t.date = '1999-01-01 00:00:00.000'
            then '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'
            else t.date
            end
from table t
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/QMI12865